# C - Print Array

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I am trying to print the elements that I add in an array in real time 
.

*Everything seems to work fine but*

**for example**

> I add the numbers 1 2 3

**But the resuls are :**  `9966656 2686588 1 2 3`

I don't know why It prints *9966656 2686588* as well and not only *1 2 3*

```
    int numbers[100] , c , x;
    char answer;
    puts("Please insert a value");

GO:
    scanf("%d", &numbers[c]);
    getchar();
    puts("Do you want to add another value? y/n");
    scanf("%c",&answer);
    if (answer == 'y') {
        c = c + 1;
        puts("Please insert another value");
        goto GO;
    } else {
        x = c;

        for (c = 0; c < x + 1; c++) {
            printf("%d ",numbers[c]);
        }
    }
```

*=====================

Let me know if you haven't understand something*

Comment: You are not discarding white space before capturing your input and also watch out that goto usage :-P

Comment: Try initializing `c = 0` at the top.

Comment: `c` is not initialised when you scan `numbers[c]`. Set it to 0 and also make sure that you don't overflow your array when `c` reaches 100.

Comment: If you think you need a `goto`, you can probably find room for improvement on the organization of the code.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to avoid goto.

Comment: How many devs thought 'uninitialized index' before opening the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is UNDEFINED since `c` is not initialized and you use it as "index" (`&numbers[c]`). This might also cause to segmentation fault and even act as you expect.

What you need to do is to set `c` to 0 at the very beginning.

Also please try avoiding `goto` unless there is a real and justified reason to use it.

Comment: I have been programming for almost 40 years.  I learned `goto` in BASIC, and might have used it briefly in C.  In all the rest of my dev years, I have never seen a need for `goto`.  I have seen it used carefully and clearly as a convention in kernel dev, but still not seen an actual need.  It gets abused, so I always find a better way.

Comment: Thank you very much fo your answers . **MARKED**

Comment: @ehem, by "abused", I mean that it can be used to get control to flow where wanted, but in very disorganized ways.  In general, it indicates to me that someone has not finished deciding clearly whether a `for` loop is best, or a `while`, or `do ... while`.  There is always a better way than `goto`, and future maintainers of your code will not enjoy your work if you use `goto` (with that kernel dev exception).

Comment: @donjuedo I have seen also `goto` where a long flow is used with various resource management. Each time one takes/acquires a resource a specific bool flag is set. Once the flow fails to take a resource or fails due to any other reason it uses `goto` to jump to the end of the flow and releases all the taken/acquired resources according to the bool flags (which tells what resource was taken and which was not). https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MEM12-C.+Consider+using+a+goto+chain+when+leaving+a+function+on+error+when+using+and+releasing+resources?src=contextnavpagetreemode

Comment: @AlexLop., I know the technique you're referring to.  When I see it, I check that it is used strictly as you said, and I move on.  But there are equivalent ways to accomplish that task, without `goto`.  I won't go so far as to say "better" because at least that use is well disciplined.  But "equivalent" is fair.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues you need to address. All of them would have been spelled out for your if you would have compiled with *Warnings Enabled* (e.g. add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compile string.) For example:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/go go.c

go.c: In function ‘main’:
go.c:17:5: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[30]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf("%c",&answer);
 ^
go.c:18:15: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
 if(answer == 'y')
```

If you address each warning until your code compiles without a warning, you then run into your primary problem:

```
for(c = 0; c < x + 1; c++)
```

`x + 1` causes your loop to read beyond the end of your data. Since you did *NOT* initialize `numbers`, it is reading garbage values that were there by default. That is another good lesson: *Always initialize your variables*.

You will also run into problem with the way you are managing `x` and `c`. `c` should only be updated on successful conversion of a decimal from the user as read by `scanf`. `scanf` provides, as it's return, the number of successful conversions. You need to use the return to check for a valid decimal entered by the users, and then update `c` only upon a successful conversion (not as the result of the user entering `y/n`.

Cleaning things up a bit, you would be better served by a slight rearrangement of your logic to something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int numbers[100] = { 0 };
    int c = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char answer[30] = { 0 };

    printf (" Please insert a value: ");

GO:

    if (scanf ("%d", &numbers[c]) == 1)
        c++;
    getchar ();
    printf (" Do you want to add another value (y/n)? ");
    scanf ("%c", answer);
    if (*answer == 'y') {
        printf (" Please insert another value: ");
        goto GO;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        printf (" number[%2d] : %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/go
 Please insert a value: 10
 Do you want to add another value (y/n)? y
 Please insert another value: 11
 Do you want to add another value (y/n)? y
 Please insert another value: 12
 Do you want to add another value (y/n)? n
 number[ 0] : 10
 number[ 1] : 11
 number[ 2] : 12
```

(note: I changed `x` to `i` - just felt more normal to iterate `i`)